# What did Isabella think Baljeet said in "Face Your Fear"?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

In the Phineas and Ferb episode *Face Your Fear*, Baljeet and Isabella have the following conversation:

> **Baljeet**: Where is Perry?
> **Isabella**: What did you say?
> **Baljeet**: I was just asking where Perry is.
> **Isabella**: Oh.
> **Baljeet**: What did you think I said?
> **Isabella**: Uh, well, I thought you said... uh... nevermind. It was too weird.

Why was Isabella confused? What did she think he said?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**"There is Barry"**

> *"Isabella's uncle Barry had been on an expedition in the Amazon and had gone missing 3 years earlier. He had been studying llama husbandry and there were all sorts of llama-conspiracy theories around his disappearance, the most prevalent of which was that he had stumbled upon a secret society of hyper intelligent llamas and was working for the head llama as an executive assistant since that had always been his dream job. **When Baljeet said "Where is Perry?" Isabella thought he said "There is Barry," like he had just seen her long lost uncle!** As you can imagine, that explanation was too long-winded and convoluted to fit into an eleven minute episode.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Only funny to me: Dan Povenmire revealed what Isabella thought Baljeet said on his TikTok.](https://www.tiktok.com/@danpovenmire/video/6886891204944858373)  Transcript courtesy of [Phineas and Ferb Wiki](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Face_Your_Fear#cite_note-2)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

Comment: So the Llama interest precede MML...